# An example for using multiclass.roc function in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, multiclass-classification

My data (insider) have a dependent variable (class) with 3 classes and 3 independent variables (type,shares,value). I partition it into train and test data then I applied multiclass logistic regression to training data set and prediction on test data set. I had 34% accuracy. Now I want to calculate area under curve with "multiclass.roc function" but I can not do it.

```
library(pROC)

library(nnet)
```

`summary(insider)`

```
#class            type            shares              value          
 buyuk:200000   al :106805   Min.   :0.000e+00   Min.   :0.000e+00  
 kucuk:150000   sat:393195   1st Qu.:3.000e+02   1st Qu.:6.651e+03  
 orta :150000                Median :1.250e+03   Median :2.810e+04  
                             Mean   :2.963e+07   Mean   :5.071e+11  
                             3rd Qu.:6.800e+03   3rd Qu.:1.793e+05  
                             Max.   :5.774e+12   Max.   :9.677e+14


set.seed(7267166)
trainIndex=createDataPartition(insider$class, p=0.7)$Resample1
train=insider[trainIndex, ]
test=insider[-trainIndex, ]
model <- nnet::multinom(class ~., data = train)
predicted.classes <- model %>% predict(test)
mean(predicted.classes == test$class)
```

`[1] 0.338`

```
multiclass.roc(test$class, predict(model, test, type = 'prob'))
```

`#Error in roc.default(response, predictor, levels = X, percent = percent,  : 
 Response and predictor must be vectors of the same length.
 In addition: Warning message:
 In roc.default(response, predictor, levels = X, percent = percent,  :
 Deprecated use a matrix as predictor. Unexpected results may be produced, 
 please pass a numeric vector.`

Comment: Please include the R libraries that you're using in your question, since `multiclass.roc` is not a base function.

Comment: I suspect that "predict(test)" returns the best predicted class - you get one result per test observation. 'predict(model, test, type="prob")' returns the probabilities for each possible class for each observation. multiclass.roc is complaining that the number of items in test$class is not the same as the number of items in the predict method (which would be nrow(test$class) * number_of_classes)